# Laravel 9 withCount on nested hasManyThrough relationship throws error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in Laravel 9 and need to add a count of my `hasManyThrough` relationship of `tiers`.

I have a `PingtreeGroup` model that defines this relationship through my `PingtreeEntry` model and works fine without doing a `withCount`, but when I add a `withCount` it throws an error.

Here's my code:

```php
$pingtreeGroup = PingtreeGroup::where('company_id', $company_id)
                                ->where('id', $id)
                                ->with('pingtrees.tiers')
                                ->withCount('pingtrees.tiers')
                                ->first();
```

The error:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\PingtreeGroup::pingtrees.tiers()

And the `tiers` relationship on the `PingtreeGroup` model:

```php
/**
 * Get the pingtrees for the model
 */
public function pingtrees()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Pingtree::class,
        PingtreeEntry::class,
        'pingtree_group_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'pingtree_id'
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: does `PingtreeGroup::first()->pingtrees` gives you the correct value?

Comment: what does `tiers` related to? `Pingtree` or `PingtreeEntry` ?

Comment: `tiers` is the hasManyThrough relationship within the `Pingtree` model

Comment: still unclear to me. looking back at the question, so `PingtreeGroup` has `hasManyThrough` relation with `Pingtree`, and `Pingtree` has `hasManyThrough` relation with `tiers` ? is that correct ?